# Determining if a closure is static in PHP

Tags: php, scope, closures, static-methods

A closure defined in PHP can also carry the `static` modifier.

```
$f = function () { };

$g = static function () { };
```

The static closure cannot be bound via [`Closure::bind`](https://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) or [`Closure::bindTo`](https://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php), and will issue a warning.

```
$g = Closure::bind(static function () { }, new stdClass());

// Warning: Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in ...
```

This is also the case of closures created by reflecting a static method with [`ReflectionMethod::getClosure`](https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php).

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function myStaticMethod() { }
}

// reflect MyClass::myStaticMethod,  create an unbound closure, and try to bind it
$f = (new ReflectionMethod(MyClass::class, 'myStaticMethod'))
    ->getClosure()
    ->bindTo(new stdClass());

// Warning: Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in ...
```

While annoying, this is acceptable; **however, how is one to test between a static and non-static closure?**

[`ReflectionMethod::isStatic`](https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isstatic.php) seemed like it *might* work, but sensibly doesn't as `Closure::__invoke` is instance-level, not static.

```
$f = static function () { };

// reflect Closure::__invoke because I think I'm tricky
$r = new ReflectionMethod($f, '__invoke');

// and it's not static anyway
var_dump($r->isStatic()); // bool(false)
```

Further, checking [`ReflectionMethod::getClosureThis`](https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php) can generally work, as a static method must be unbound, however that doesn't cover closures defined outside an instance method, or the corner-case of instance methods that have been *unbound*.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function myInstanceMethod() { }
}

$o = new MyClass();

// reflect MyClass::myInstanceMethod, create a bound closure, and then unbind it
$f = (new ReflectionMethod($o, 'myInstanceMethod'))
    ->getClosure($o)
    ->bindTo(null);

// then reflect the closure
$r = new ReflectionFunction($f);

// and see it's bound to nothing, as would be the case of a static closure
var_dump($r->getClosureThis()); // NULL
```

So, to restate, **how do you determine whether a closure is static (*or more specifically, bindable*) or not?**

It really seems as though we should have a `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::isBindable`, or that `ReflectionMethod::isStatic` be moved up to `ReflectionFunctionAbstract`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If binding works, the Closure will have a $this bound to it. So, just bind it and then check for the $this. If it's null, well, then it's a static Closure.

```
function isBindable(\Closure $closure) {
    $boundClosure = @\Closure::bind($closure, new stdClass);

    return $boundClosure && (new ReflectionFunction($boundClosure))->getClosureThis() != null; 
}
```

Comment: This is the only way I've seen so far.

Comment: Likewise. I don't like that it's dirty because of `@`, but it works reliably, and there aren't any corner cases I can find.

Answer (score 3):

It seems impossible now.
You can find some debates here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64761
The only real workaround I use for myself now is adding `->isBindable` property manually.

Here's some code I found here https://github.com/atoum/atoum/blob/master/classes/test/adapter/invoker.php
Maybe will give you a few ideas

```
protected static function isBindable(\closure $closure)
    {
        $isBindable = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0);
        if ($isBindable === true)
        {
            $reflectedClosure = new \reflectionFunction($closure);
            $isBindable = ($reflectedClosure->getClosureThis() !== null || $reflectedClosure->getClosureScopeClass() === null);
        }
        return $isBindable;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where it's bindable, but not bound to anything nor having a scope class.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but still shows up in google search. The mentioned `isStatic` nowadays exists in `ReflectionFunction`,as of php 8.1 (I tested it out)

```php
$fn = static fn() => true;
$refl = new ReflectionFunction($fn);

$refl->isStatic(); // returns true
```

```php
$fn = fn() => true;
$refl = new ReflectionFunction($fn);

$refl->isStatic(); // returns false
```

It does not show up in documentation as of writing.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

I also created a missing doc report here: https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/2136